# POSIXロケール LC_CTYPEカテゴリのtranslit_startなどはどこから来たのか？

Tags: posix, locale

[POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07)では、ロケールに対してLC_CTYPEを含む6つのカテゴリが定められています。

一方、[LC_ADDRESS等がglibcによって拡張された](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/locale.5.html)ようです。（何故か[glibcマニュアル](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Locales)には載ってませんが）

ここで、ロケール定義ファイルを見ていると、LC_CTYPEの中でtranslit_startなどのキーワードを見かけます。これはPOSIX.1では規定されていませんが、先のLinuxマニュアルには載っています。そして、glibc拡張であるとは記載されていません。

Linuxマニュアルの末尾にはこうあります。

> CONFORMING TO
> POSIX.2.

しかし、POSIX.2について[調べてみると、POSIX初版の1つであり](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)、内容的にもロケールとは関係なく、その後POSIX.1に統合されているように見えます。

以上から、タイトルの質問になります。
POSIXロケール LC_CTYPEカテゴリのtranslit_startなどはどこから来たのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

断定的な回答はできないのですが、調べた限りでは [JTC1/SC22/WG20 Internationalization](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg20/) によるI18N仕様検討が起源の可能性が高いです。

`translit_start`への言及は下記WG20文書でヒットします。

- 1998-10-21 [N613: Relation between 14652 and 15435](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg20/docs/N613.TXT)
- 1998-12-21 [N634: ISO/IEC FCD2 14652](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg20/docs/n634.pdf)

前者によると [ISO/IEC 14652 Specification method for cultural conventions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg20/docs/n972-14652ft.pdf) で定義されていそうですが、2002-08-12付けのFinal Textでは直接的に見つけられませでした。WG20では [ISO/IEC 15435 - Internationalization APIs](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1027.pdf) の策定を目指していたもの、最終ステータスは不明です（少なくともISO/IECサイト上で存在確認できません）。

なお glibc への変更コミットは 1999-08-31 に行われていました。
https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/4b10dd6c1959577f57850ca427a94fe22b9f3299

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。いくつかのことがわかりました。

まず、ISO/IEC 14652ですが、たしかに`translit_start`というキーワード自体はありませんが、Final Textの4.9節でtransliterationの概念は提唱されているようです。ここでは`LC_XLITERATE`カテゴリを検討していたようですが、`controversial`とあるのでこれで決まりとはならなかった（実際そうなっていない）ようですね。  
また、Annex Aでは"Differences from the ISO/IEC 9945-2 standard"とあり、ISO/IEC 9945-2とはまさにPOSIX.2のことなので、"Conforming to POSIX.2"の意味がわかりました。

ISO/IEC 15435は最終的には撤回されたようです。 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg20/docs/W-SD3.htm "withdrawn" とあります。

glibcへの変更は1999年とのことですが、1998年には`translit_start`というキーワードが登場していた。しかし2002年のFinal Textでは定義されていない。なかなか難しいですね。

Answer (score 3):

@yohjp さんの回答を受けて、更に調査してみて、以下の結論になりました。

JTC1/SC22/WG20によるi18nの検討は[95年から始まっていたと見られる](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG20/docs/n400.htm)。この頃から`translit_start`キーワードが使われ、それがglibcに取り込まれた可能性が高い。
これらの活動結果はTR 14652として公表されたものの、`translit_start`ではなく`LC_XLITERATE`カテゴリを定義した。また、標準化には至らず、2004年に解散した。

その後、i18nの活動は[JTC1/SC35/WG5](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc35/wg5/)によって行われ、2014年にISO/IEC 30112として標準化された。[2014年のドラフト](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc35/wg5/docs/30112d10.pdf)では`translit_start`が定義されている。`LC_XLITERATE`カテゴリも消えてはいないが、Annex Eにあるように、glibcはこれをサポートしていない。
2018年に規格の改定が行われたが、[2018年のドラフト](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc35/wg5/docs/30112d12.pdf)でも状況は変わっていない。